# Why it's not required to use await keyword in onPressed function?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why it's not required to use await keyword in onPressed function? For instance, there is a *url_launcher* plugin. The usage is as follows:

```
onPressed: _launchURL,
...
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Is not it required in dart to use await keyword before calling an async function? Then why we don't use *await* keyword before the `_launchURL` in `onPressed`?

Comment: because there you are not defining the function and not executing it, you just assign it to some property, and then someone will do await onPressed()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in the comments you are not calling the function so there is nothing to await.
However, `onPressed` actually expects any function with the `void` return type meaning that it will not await any function you give it.

So basically the onPressed is just initiating the future and then forgetting about it